# Is the indirection operator needed when printing out the value of a pointer?

Tags: c

I'm reading a book on the c language and have a question about one of its string pointer examples.

```
int x;
char *str = "Food";
printf("Pointer variable value: %p\n", *str);
printf("Pointer points to: %s\n", str);
printf("Memory locations of chars are: \n");

for(x = 0; x < 5; x++)
   printf("%p\n", str[x]);
```

Why is the indirection operator needed in front of the string name in the first `printf`, and why is the address-of operator not needed in the `for` loop `printf`?

However, when I execute this program, the two 'o' characters actually have the same address. When I add the address-of operator in front of `str[x]` the addresses become contiguous.

Comment: The example is wrong – it should pass `str` for the first `%p`, not `*str`, and `&str[x]` or `str + x` for the second `%p`, not `str[x]`. Which book is it? D=

Comment: Please always show exact code. Use copy&paste whenever possible. What type specifier do they use then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line is wrong.

```
printf("Pointer variable value: %p\n", *str);
```

To print the pointer, the second argument needs to be just `str`.

```
printf("Pointer variable value: %p\n", str);
```

The following line is also wrong.

```
printf("%p\n", str[x]);
```

To print the pointer, change the second argument to `&str[x]`.

```
printf("%p\n", &str[x]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`%p` is used to print the pointer.

From C Standard#7.21.6.1p8

> p
>   The argument shall be a pointer to void. The value of the pointer is converted to a sequence of printing characters, in an implementation-defined manner.

The compiler must be giving warning message on these two statements:

```
printf("Pointer variable value: %p\n", *str);
```

and

```
printf("%p\n", str[x]);
```

The reason is `%p` expecting pointer to `void` type and you are giving a `char` type.

The `*str` is equivalent to `*(str + 0)` and `*(str + 0)` is `str[0]` which is a character at first location of string `str`.

So, if you want to print a pointer then you should give `str` instead of `*str` and if you want to print the address of each character of string then you should give `&str[x]`.

The operator `&` is used to get the address and the operator `*` is used for dereferencing.

So,

```
str[x] -> *(str + x)
&str[x] -> &(*(str + x))
```

These operator `&` and `*` cancel the effect of each other when used one after another. Hence, this

```
&(*(str + x)) -> (str + x)
```

`str + x` is address of character at location `x`.

So, the correct statements are:

```
printf("Pointer variable value: %p\n", str);
```

and

```
printf("%p\n", &str[x]);
```